# Constantly check if process is running C#

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to determine if a process is open by looking for the process's name like this:

```
Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("process name");
if (proc.Length != 0)
{
    proccess_running = true;
}
else
{
    process_running = false;
}
```

And then in a status-bar display the result to the user like this:

```
if (process_running == true)
{
    statusBar1.Text = "Process is running";
}
else
{
    statusBar1.Text = "Process is not running";
}
```

I tried putting the above inside a timer, which gives the correct result, except the text flickers every time the timer ticks.

Would there be a way to only set the status-bar's text only if the bool (process_running) has changed and not when the timer ticks?

Comment: Have you double buffering turned on on you form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = process_running ? "Process is running" : "Process is not running";
if (statusBar1.Text != text)
    statusBar1.Text = text;
```

Comment: Thinking outside the box. nice :) Or keep the bool status and check that each time....

Comment: Awesome solution! Works exactly as expected.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sure, keeping `bool` would be faster, but I do not think that it is important in our case, and wanted a shorter code. (After all, I had to type it :-)). Also, saved `bool` could make the logic more complicated. E.g. at the beginning — should it be `false` or `true`?

Comment: "E.g. at the beginning — should it be false or true" - It should be calculated in exactly the same way as the label and setting it to false before checking if it is running is 100% correct.

Comment: @MitchWheat I meant if we rely on the condition `old_process_running != process_running` to display the text, we need to make a trick to do it for the very first time. Alternative is to split initialization and update, but it is a bit cumbersome. But anyway, I guess we are talking about more or less the same thing.